# Why does this cast to Base class in virtual function give a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, virtual, segmentation-fault, casting

I want to print out a derived class using the `operator<<`. When I print the derived class, I want to first print its base and then its own content.

But I ran into some trouble (see segfault below):

```
class Base {
 public:
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Base&);
  virtual void Print(std::ostream& out) const {
    out << "BASE!";
  }
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Base& b) {
  b.Print(out);
  return out;
}

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  virtual void Print(std::ostream& out) const {
    out << "My base: ";
    //((const Base*)this)->Print(out); // infinite, calls this fct recursively
    //((Base*)this)->Print(out);       // segfault (from infinite loop?)                                                          
    ((Base)*this).Print(out);          // OK
    out << " ... and myself.";
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    Derived d;
    std::cout << d;
    return 0;
}
```

Why can't I cast in one of these ways?

```
    ((const Base*)this)->Print(out); // infinite, calls this fct recursively
    ((Base*)this)->Print(out);       // segfault (from infinite loop?)
```

Comment: As a small piece of advice: Any time you're doing an explicit cast in C++, you're *probably* doing something wrong. Casts should be used sparingly, if at all, and only when you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Base::Print(out)

Answer (score 4):

To the question of *why*:

1. `((Base)*this).Print(out);` *slices* current instance to `Base`-typed temporary. That results in a direct call to base class method.
2. `((const Base*)this)->Print(out);` calls virtual method through a pointer to base, which resolves to the child class method, which results in infinite recursion.
3. `((Base*)this)->Print(out);` - I'm pretty sure this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Why are the 3th different with 2th? I think they cause the same infinite recursion.

Comment: Because it casts out constness.

Comment: Get it! I didn't notice the const specifier. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use `Base::Print` instead.  Virtual functions are overriden by derived class.
In essence you are calling print over and over

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading C++ Primer 5th page 607 "Circumventing the Virtual Mechanism" which is a short section talking about the kind of infinite-recursion error you made.